# Jquery to increase font size of HTML contents in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the javascript I used to increase the font size of all HTML contents within #myContent. The strange thing here is that whenever increaseFontSize() is invoked, the font size does not get increased, instead it gets reduced. Can some kind souls advise on what I have done wrong. Thank you.

I put up an alert on fontSizeStr and fontSize. fontSizeStr reads 14 while fontSize reads 12. The last line should change the contents to 12px but it does not. The font decreased.

```
:
:
function increaseFontSize() {
   var fontSizeStr = $("#myContent").css('font-size');
   var fontSize = parseInt (fontSizeStr,10) + 2;
   $("#myContent").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
}
:
:
:
<div id="myContent">
    <html>
    :
    :
    <p>Actual Contents 1</p>
    <p>Actual Contents 2</p>
    :
    :
    </html>
</div>
:
:
```

**[Updates]**: 
- Added "px" to the end of the fontSize. 
- Changed from "fontSize" to "font-size"

Answer (score 1):

You need to update

```
 $("#myContent").css("fontSize", fontSize);
```

to

```
 $("#myContent").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It still shrink the font instead of increasing the font-size. I tested the code in both devices (through Phonegap) that run different Android versions (4.3, 4.4). Not sure why it works on 1 device but not on another.

Comment: This should work. The problem with setting font-size is the one I mentioned in answer. There seems to be some other issues like what is html tag doing inside div? Additionally, it will be great if you create a fiddle/plunker for the same

Answer (score 1):

please add `-` in `fontSize` like  `font-size`

```
$("#myContent").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
```

Use

```
var fontSizeStr= fontSizeStr.substring(0,fontSizeStr.length-2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It still shrink the font instead of increasing the font-size. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you add `!mportant`  like this `$("#myContent").css("font-size", fontSize + "px !important");` or try one more thing first try to set fix value like `.css("font-size", "40px");`  and check if it works

Comment: You can't add `!important` through jQuery's `css` function

Comment: Thank you for replying... Adding "!important" does not cause any changes to the contents. But .css("font-size", "40px") does increase the font-size. Isn't this strange?

Comment: Yes, Thanks @winhowes i have just checked `!important` it is not working

Comment: Check if you are getting value in `fontSize` variable ?

Comment: first try to set `var fontSize = 40;` if it works then please check the code `var fontSizeStr = $("#myContent").css('font-size');
   var fontSize = parseInt (fontSizeStr,10) + 2;` there may be problem

Comment: alert (fontSizeStr) produces 14px while alert (fontSize + "px") produces 12px.

Comment: So this is not working `parseInt (fontSizeStr,10) + 2` because `fontSizeStr=14px` which contains `px` which is not parsing into int so it is returning the `12`

Comment: The alert after parseInt shows 12 (from 14px). So parseInt works. In my understanding, "px" (which appears after a legit number) will be ignored when parseInt parses a string. The font got reduced instead of increased, which puzzles me for quite some time.

Comment: use `var fontSize = fontSizeStr.substring( 0,fontSizeStr.length-2);`

Comment: It should be var fontSize = fontSizeStr.substring(0,fontSizeStr.length-2); to retrieve the numbers.

Comment: yes i was editing the code .i pressed enter mistakenly.i have edited the comment

Comment: Use `var fontSizeStr= fontSizeStr.substring(0,fontSizeStr.length-2);` donot assign the `substring` result to `fontSize`

Comment: var fontSizeStr = $("#myContent").css('font-size');
fontSizeStr = fontSizeStr.substring(0,fontSizeStr.length-2);
var newFontSize = parseInt (fontSizeStr,10) + 2;
$("#myContent").css("font-size", newFontSize + "px");

The font still gets reduced instead of increase...

Comment: I have check it in firebug console it is working fine.this is the last solution.there may be some other problem

Answer (score 0):

```
function increaseFontSize() {
   var fontSizeStr = $("#myContent").css('font-size');
   var fontSize = fontSizeStr.substring(fontSizeStr.length-2, fontSizeStr.length);
   var newFontSize = parseInt (fontSize,10) + 2;
   $("#myContent").css("font-size", newFontSize + "px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustaf, appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It still shrink the font instead of increasing the font-size. Not sure why....

Comment: Do you want to increase size for `<p>Actual Contents 1</p>` and `<p>Actual Contents 2</p>` etc??

Comment: I want to increase the text within the DIV.

Comment: It should be `$("#myContent").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");` instead of `$("#myContent").css("fontSize", fontSize + "px");`, note `font-size` instead of `fontSize` Try with the updated answer!!

Comment: Have corrected it to "font-size" but the output is still the same.

Comment: Have corrected to:
var fontSize = fontSizeStr.substring(0,fontSizeStr.length-2);

Still cannot work.

Comment: @benjamin try with this.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I have updated your code to use the following to get the numbers from the String: var fontSize = fontSizeStr.substring(fontSizeStr.length-2, fontSizeStr.length);  The result is still the same... I used PhoneGap, Jquerymobile and Jquery. My code works well on Samsung S3 but not on Samsung S6. I guess my code is correct just that it responds differently on different phones... The bug could be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code of JSFIDDLE.

http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/xju2xksp/1/

```
<div id="myContent">
    <p>Actual Contents 1</p>
    <p>Actual Contents 2</p>
</div>
<button onClick="increaseFontSize()">Click Me</button>
```

Tested in my localhost, with html tags, its working fine.